# env: ‘jupyter’: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to apply this [tuto](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-ubuntu-pyspark-231c45677de0) in my ubuntu, and this is what i did:

1-install spark 2.2.... (pyspark)+ java(1.8) + anaconda (Python2.7)

2-edit the .bachrc (adding 2 lines):

`export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter`

`export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"`

3-lanch Pyspark: `$sudo Pyspark` it works fine

4-lanch jupyter: `$sudo jupyther notebook` it works fine

when i run `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter" PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"  spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark` the command to launch Pyspark with Jupyter notebook i get this:

```
env: ‘jupyter’: No such file or directory
```

what should i do ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i type `which jupyter` not thing is displayed on my terminal so i fixed the issue by Uninstalling anaconda and installing it again from anaconda official [site](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/linux.html), now it works fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

Shell cannot find `juptyer`in your environment in any of the directories listed in `$PATH`. If you have followed the tutorial and installed `Anaconda` distribution, you should have added the path to `$PATH` in `.bashrc`:

```
echo 'export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Also check that `jupyter` is present in `~/anaconda/bin"`. Note that `~` refers to `$HOME` so you should adapt the path if your installation is located elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error, I uninstalled anaconda by removing the anaconda directory. I then installed it from the anaconda website and updated my bash profile to reflect on the new location of anaconda in my "/" (root) directory. Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution by MaFF and it worked --- the installation may have failed to add the PATH to the env. so I manually added it as suggested by MaFF, uninstall and reinstall is not necessary.